# Use Javascript to add a character after the text in a list element, but before an indented list and without spaces between the text and the addition

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to add with regular Javascript to add a character to the text in a list element, but before an indented list occurs AND to have said character to not have an space between it and the original text? The actual text I have to use is not fixed.

Like, if I have this HTML:

```
  <ul>
      <li>Uno
        <ul>
               <li>One</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Dos
        <ul>
               <li>Two</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Use Javascript only to add a colon immediately after «Uno» and «Dos», like:

- Uno:

  - One
- Dos:

  - Two

But avoiding this result, which has an space in it (and pretty much any solution I can think of has that issue. I wouldn't had much control over the HTML as I want to use it between a regular WordPress page):

- Uno :

  - One
- Dos :

  - Two

Comment: You should share your effort and point out the part you are having trouble with, this is not a free programming website!

Comment: sure you could do that just with vanilla css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 //Get all LI which are immediate child of root UL
    let immediateLi = document.querySelectorAll('body > ul > li');

    //loop through the Li array and edit text node.
    for(let li of immediateLi) {
        li.childNodes[0].textContent = li.childNodes[0].textContent.trim() + ':'
    }

    //Important Note:
    //I have selected 0th child-node from the array because it is the default text-node containing our text. In case you are not sure if 0th child-node will hold the text content then you may filter the child-node array.
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Uno
      <ul>
             <li>One</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Dos
      <ul>
             <li>Two</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I've also accounted for the case where the list item doesn't contain a nested unordered list.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("ul li:not(ul ul li)").forEach(e => {
  let html = e.innerHTML;
  var index = html.indexOf("<ul>");
  if(index == -1)
  {
    index = html.trim().length;
  }
  else
  {
    while(html[--index] == " " && index > 0){}
  }
  
  e.innerHTML = html.substr(0, index) + ":" + (
    html.length > index ?
      html.substr(index) :
      ""
  );
});
```

```html
<ul>
      <li>Uno
        <ul>
               <li>One</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Dos
        <ul>
               <li>Two</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Tres         </li>
  </ul>
```